# TensorFlow 2.2.0 not importing Sequential from tensorflow.keras.models PyVer==3.8

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

Here below the error showing up after trying to run, the error does not persist if rolling back top Tensorflow 2.0 version.
When autocompleting in Jupyter Notebook all sections are showing up normally, just fails to load.
Any possible workaround to avoid rolling back to older version?

In:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

Out:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f05745da3b73> in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     48 import numpy as np
     49 
---> 50 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     51 
     52 # Protocol buffers

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     67 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     68 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 69   raise ImportError(msg)
     70 
     71 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michele\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Michele\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Michele\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Michele\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Michele\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the latest TensorFlow version >= 2.2.0, the developers have modified the way (made it easier) to load the models/layers etc.

Therefore, the Sequential class is not longer in the package `tensorflow.keras.models` but in `tensorflow.keras`

Comment: It was that simple afterall, thanks for the clarification. I could not find that in the documentation anywhere, are you able to share where it was posted?

Comment: No, I tried on my own in my free time and saw how the modifications; at the same time it is very probable that the new documentation on TensorFlow is updated with the new implementation examples

Answer (score 1):

you can do these examples of the sequential model in TensorFlow Keras.you can also add layers according to your case.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential

model = Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add an output layer with 10 output units:
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
```

**or**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add an output layer with 10 output units:
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
```